# How to get Trashcan Carla out of my power armor?

Tags: fallout-4

Sanctuary got attacked by raiders. When it was finished Trashcan Carla was in my best power armor. I always leave my PA without a core in them, but she still got in it. So I can't pickpocket the core, because there is none in it! Guess it's a bug or did something change and can some people use the power armor without core? Luckily I had a recent savefile, but how to solve it when it happens again. Talking to her does not work, no option to make her leave it like with settlers and followers.

Comment: Try interacting from within Workshop mode? Otherwise Try telling her to get into a garbage PA frame, seeing if she gets out? (Then cancel the order)

Comment: Try to pickpocket the core back in, and then try and pickpocket it back out?

Comment: It's probably a bug. The player's the only one who drains Fusion Cores while in Power Armor, so the engine probably forgot to check if there was a core before letting Carla in. "*Pickpocket the core in, leave the pickpocket interface, then pickpocket it out again*" seems like a sensible solution.

Comment: Putting a core back in and then removing it was something I thought about after I reloaded. Seems like a possible way around this bug indeed. Will try to verify if I get it again.

Comment: @Robotnik Trashcan Carla isn't a companion, so you can't tell her to get into a different PA frame.

Comment: She's a merchant. She probably had her own fusion core.

Comment: Can you just pickpocket the important armor bits off and transfer them to another frame?

Comment: She's the only NPC I've ever murdered (all the others were self-defense!).  She was hanging out MY town being rude to me every time I came near and never leaving, I finally just shot her.  And deleted her corpse, because it also refused to leave.  :D

Comment: You can also force someone out of armor by shooting the power core. Can you target the power core in VATS?

Comment: Can't you just kill her and then take the armor back afterwards?

Answer (score 10):

How to get the *trash out of the can*, you mean? There's at least one option: [Bunker Hill](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Bunker_Hill).

[image: Bunker Hill aerial view]

Random caravans will stop there from time to time - [Trashcan Carla's](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Trashcan_Carla) included.

She's an educated person and will leave her armor before talking to her clients.

[image: Trashcan Carla at Bunker Hill]

It's not exactly easy to find her there, though - I had to pay several visits (waiting didn't work for me).

Answer (score 5):

You could just kill her and take it from her corpse. Not really any reason to keep her alive shes an unimportant npc.

Comment: killing NPCs whilst they're still in power armor does not grant you the frame. OP would only be able to loot the pieces of armor off the corpse.

Comment: You can get frames anywhere, the pieces are the valuable part for OP - "best power armor"

Comment: She's a /useful/ NPC though, so just simply killing her isn't an option for those who utilize her trading services often.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can always kill her and loot the armor off of her, since it's not that hard to find another frame. The alternative is fast traveling away and then fast traveling back I've heard that works.You could also try to put a fusion core in then go into Vats and shoot it I've heard rumours the suit can sustain the explosion. I was also thinking maybe you could trade with them take the power armor leave the frame. Since there's so many Power Armor Frames everyhwere.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried talking to her and asking her to get out of the power armor.
It took me a while to work out how to get nick out of a set i had lying around, however i had asked him to get into the power armor in the first place.

Comment: Trashcan carla is NOT a follower like Nick, she is a vendor. Like I said in my original question, there was no option to ask her to leave the PA like you can with followers or setters.

Answer (score -1):

Just had the same issue shoot her dead it’s the quickest way out of it. Frames are 1000 caps or find one it’s not that hard. Also there are mods for resources if your concerned about the junk cost to repair king of sanctuary gives 250 k of each resource.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade! Your solution is already given, and the rest is general advice. There is also some punctuation missing. Please take the [Tour] to get acquainted with our platform.

Answer (score -4):

Try and pickpocket the fusion core off of her then she will jump out

Comment: "I can't pickpocket the core, because there is none in it"