# Ronnie Shaw stole my power armor, how to get it back

Tags: fallout-4

So I was in the castle and then I realized my power armor was gone. I looked around and bam, Ronnie Shaw had on my X01 power armor. I tried talking to them but no dice, and I tried pickpocketing but the they and the minutemen become hostile. How can I boot an NPC from my power armor?

Comment: Great, I just saw Ronnie and she’s out of it. Now I can’t find my power armor. Damn you Ronnie Shaw!

Comment: Fairly related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246908/how-to-get-trashcan-carla-out-of-my-power-armor

Comment: Ronnie Shaw, that's rich. She's old, let her have it. It's a nice gesture.

Answer (score 8):

Whenever you park a power armor, take out the power cell. NPCs only use armor that is operational.

Comment: Thanks. I found it sitting outside the minutemen broadcast tower. Guess she doesn’t want it. But it was mostly for X6 88 since I found a set of X01 Mk lll

Comment: I have found, in limited hours of play, that when I park my power armor in a power armor station, it stays there even if the fusion cell is still in it. Does this work, or is it just a matter of time before someone walks off with my power armor?

Comment: In a matter of time someone will take it. Just build a player home where you can keep your stuff. I did it and you don’t have to worry about NPCs. Also maybe there might be a mod where you can make sure that NPCs won’t take your power armor.